# Erro em código para detecção de letra

Tags: c, comparação

Estou trabalhando em um código para detecção de letra com a utilização de uma função, para um exercício de aula. A ideia é que quando eu digita uma letra a função detecte se ela for:

- maiscula = 1
- minuscula = 0
- outra coisa = -1.

Este retornos de 1, 0 e -1 retorna para a `main()`.

O meu retorno esta sempre -1.

```
    int main()
    {
    char le;
    int x; x=0;

    printf ( " \n Programa que detecta se a letra e maiuscula e ou 
    minuscula");

    printf (" \nDigite uma letra : ");
    scanf ("%s", &le);

    detletra (l);

    if  ( x = 0)
    {
         printf (" \n A letra digitada e minuscula! "  );
    }
    else if  ( x = 1)
    {
         printf (" \n A letra digitada e maiscula! "  );
    }
    else if  ( x = -1)
    {
         printf (" \n A letra digitada não pertence ao alfabeto "  );
    }

    printf ( " \n %d", x);
    }


    void detletra ( char letra ) // função  processamento dos dados
    {
    if (letra >= 'a' &&  letra <= 'z') // Verifica se a letra é minuscula
    {
    int x;
    x = 0;
    return x; // retorna o valor para main
    }
    else if (letra >= 'A' && letra <= 'Z' ) // Verifica se a letra é maiscula
    {
    int x;
    x = 1;
    return x; // retorna o valor para main
    }
    else // Verifica se a letra não é do alfabeto
    {
    int x;
    x = -1;
    return x; // retorna o valor para main
    }

    }
```

Comment: o tipo de retorno do metodo esta como void

Comment: alem de nao passar o retorno da funcao para a variavel x

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, no caso se eu mudar para int, o compilador reclama a mensagem |D:\UNISSINOS\linguagem c\Trabalho 1 _v2\main.c|32|error: conflicting types for 'detletra'| D:\UNISSINOS\linguagem c\Trabalho 1 _v2\main.c|33|note: an argument type that has a default promotion can't match an empty parameter name list declaration|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem vários erros, alguns mais críticos que outros. Vamos lá.

A função deve retornar um tipo de dado inteiro, conforme a definição do problema e não um tipo que não retorna valor.

A variável `x` não está recebendo o valor retorna pela função, mudei isso pegando esse retorno. Talvez achou que o `x` de uma função é a mesma coisa do `x` da outra função, mas não é, por isso que retorna algo.

A comparação se faz com o operador `==` e não o `=` que é o operador de atribuição, então você está mudando o valor de `x` de forma inadequada no lugar que acha que está comparando algo.

Para pedir uma letra deve usar a formatação `%c` e não `%s`.

Melhorei os nomes dos identificadores (deixei o `x` que poderia ter melhor nome), eles são importante para dar legibilidade no código. E tirei comentários que não ajudavam em nada entender oque está acontecendo ali, só dizia obviedades, comentário não é para isto. E claro, organizei muito o código, tirei um monte de coisa que não era necessária e mantive um padrão.

Uma mudança mais radical que fiz foi simplificar a comparação das letras. O valor de uma comparação já é um número 0 ou 1, então pode usar o resultado para evitar parte do código. E mesmo que usasse o `if` como uso no primeiro caso, não precisa declarara a [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101), atribuir um valor para ela e depois usar esse valor, não tem porque usar variável ali, use o valor direto.

Como retorna 1 para verdadeiro e 0 para falso e eu quero que retorno 0 ou -1 então subtraio 1 do resultado. Mas esse conta só ocorre que já não ficou no `if` anterior que retorna o 1.

Acertar a ordem das comparações é algo que um programador tem que pensar, pode simplificar muito o código. E conhecer todos os mecanismos da linguagem para usar de forma adequada e simples.

Olha como o código pode ficar muito menor:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int detecta(char letra) {
    if (letra >= 'A' && letra <= 'Z') return 1;
    else return (letra >= 'a' && letra <= 'z') - 1;
}

int main() {
    char letra;
    printf("Programa que detecta se a letra e maiuscula e ou minuscula");
    printf("\nDigite uma letra: ");
    scanf("%c", &letra);
    int x = detecta(letra);
    if (x == 0) printf("\nA letra digitada e minuscula!");
    else if (x == 1) printf("\nA letra digitada e maiscula!");
    else if (x == -1) printf("\nA letra digitada não pertence ao alfabeto");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/VaUnyc). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/niyeprwd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/UpperLower.c).

Entenda o que cada parte, o que cada caractere do código faz, assim organiza melhor, deixa mais legível, e passa saber oque está acontecendo ali, sem parecer uma magia.

Comment: Obrigado Maneiro, vou tomar mais cuidado nos identificadores e retomar alguns conceitos que eu estou confundindo.